# bash terminal history search in vi mode

Tags: bash, command-history, vi-mode

I would like to be able to type pi [up-arrow] and have bash automatically go to previous command that started with pi for example `ping -c 4 8.8.8.8` in vi mode

I can get emacs mode to do this after I put the following code in my .inputrc

```
"\C-[OA": history-search-backward
"\C-[[A": history-search-backward
"\C-[OB": history-search-forward
"\C-[[B": history-search-forward
```

Is there any code magic I can put in my .inputrc or .bashrc to get this behavior when I am in vi mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bash has a similar feature built-in: Type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd> and start typing. This will search in you command history. It brings up the last command that matches. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd> to search again for older commands.